# Azure login with database

Tags: database, azure, authentication, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a login system on an asp.net website which allows a user to register and log in the website. I require the registered user details to be stored on a database which I already have on Azure.

I have so far created the login system as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508981.aspx and the form works. However, when I log in to the azure management portal I cannot find the user's registered details. I also need to add more fields to the registration form in the database.

Does anyone know where I can view the registered users and how I can add more fields?

Comment: Why would you think that the user's register details would be in the "Azure Management Portal".  ASP.NET membership information is just stored in a database.  The "Azure Management Portal" does nothing special with the contents of those databases.  You could use the management portal to query your database--which is as close as you get to "finding the user's registered details" in Azure Management Portal.  Maybe if you're specific about what you expect the portal to be able to do in this case...

Comment: As you might have guessed I'm a beginner with Azure C# etc... but what I'm basically trying to do is a login and registration form where the user's details can be stored on a database on Azure where I can be able to see what the data inputted is. I'm not sure if I have clarified my question.

Comment: Azure Portal is the equivalent of SQL Server Management Studio.  Just as Management Studio doesn't know anything about your ASP.NET users, neither does the Portal.  You can query your membership database as just another database.  You need to query that database with other software, maybe https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit or the ASP.NET Web Site Adminstration tool http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Site_Administration_Tool

Comment: If I query the database inside the Management Portal of the SQL Database on Azure will I get the same results? (I have tried querying the Membership database and I got no fields for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the same link you used to create your application you will see the schema that is used by SQL Azure to store this information as below:

[image]

Now if you want to access this database directly, what you really need is SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to connect with this Database and access it from your local machine. Follow this link below to download and configure SQL Azure studio locally so you can connect to SQL  database and the modify the schema or look the records etc. Once you have SSMS connected with SQL Database, you can manage it like any other on-premise database.

[Managing Windows Azure SQL Database using SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/sql-azure-management/)

Comment: I have downloaded SSMS and I can view the tables. However, every time I register a new user, no records show when I query the Membership table. Any ideas why?